How many objects of mutex, semorphore or condition variables could a process initiate up to?
It's obvious to me that virtual address space of a process turns out to be limit the number of objects of futex, mutex, semorphore or condition variables may never be created up to. Is there other such limit in linux for a process not to create as many pthread objects as they may require in C/C++?
If there is a data structure in kernel to manage, then how should I raise the limit?

The kernel uses a fixed number of wait queues to handle all the fuxexes, so creating a futex does not use up kernel memory.
